# std::vector - thread safety and resize options

Tags: c++, vector, thread-safety, mutex

I'm getting a rare program crash which I believe (I'm fairly sure) is happening when a vector which is accessed across threads is resized. I've added a mutex to the push back function (below). I think I might be seeing some cases where the vector is caused to be resized in another thread X, while thread Y is trying to copy a value from one of the vectors members - which results in a copied size of 0, later causing a std::out_of_range access.

```
class TvectorPM {
public:
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    std::vector<PopulationMember> v;

    TvectorPM();
    virtual ~TvectorPM();

    void add(PopulationMember p);
};

void TvectorPM::add(PopulationMember p) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    v.push_back(p);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

I'm not keen on adding a mutex for a vector read because most places in the code only need to read and performance is a big issue for this software. Below is a pseudo example of what's going on

```
void EvolutionManager::mutateSingleNode(int num_needed, int pool_size) {
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
        for (int x = 0; x < num_needed; x ++) {
            // Copy the original RPN Vec, create a new member
            int rand_member = tornament(pool_size);
            PopulationMember p;
            p.rpn_node_vec = population_manager.populationlist.v.at(rand_member).rpn_node_vec;
            p.change();
            population_manager.populationlist.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that I could

a) - Take the performance hit and mutex the read

b) - Check that the size of p.rpn_node_vec is > 0 or re-read (again some performance hit, and hacky)

c) - Ask you good people if there is a way to allocate extra memory to the vector before I start the loop to avoid the need to resize?

Comment: `std::vector::reserve()` or `std::vector::resize()` will allow you to set aside as much memory as you like.

Comment: without initialising members for the extra memory?

Comment: Yeah reserve has done it. Feel quite silly to have lost ~3 hours finding this bug... If you want to make an answer I can accept. Very grateful for the fast correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preallocate memory for a vector, there are a few ways to do it:

```
// constructor parameter, creates 100 default constructed objects
// giving v1.size() == 100;
std::vector<int> v1(100);

std::vector<int> v2;

// resize() will actually resize the vector making size match the parameter passed in
v2.resize(100);

// again, v2.size() == 100;

std::vector<int> v3;

// reserve just "sets aside" memory for the vector to use later
v3.reserve(100);

// now, v3.size() == 0, but v3.capacity() == 100
```